# Merge Multiple Worksheets from Multiple Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have found multiple posts on merging data but I am still running into some problems. I have multiple files with multiple sheets. Example 2007-01.xls...2007-12.xls in each of these files are daily data on sheets labeled 01, 02, 03 ..... There are other sheets in the file so I can't just loop through all worksheets. I need to combine the daily data into monthly data, then all of the monthly data points into yearly.

On the monthly data I need it to be added to the bottom of the page.

I have added the file open changes for Excel 2007

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub RunCodeOnAllXLSFiles() 
Dim lCount As Long 
Dim wbResults As Workbook 
Dim wbMaster As Workbook 

Application. ScreenUpdating = False 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
Application.EnableEvents = False 

On  Error Resume Next 

Set wbMaster =  ThisWorkbook 


Dim oWbk As Workbook 
Dim sFil As String 
Dim sPath As String 

sPath = "C:\Users\test\" 'location of files
ChDir sPath 
sFil = Dir("*.xls") 'change or add  formats
Do While sFil <> "" 'will start LOOP until all files in folder sPath have been looped through Set oWbk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\" & sFil) 'opens the file

    Set oWbk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\" & sFil) 

    Sheets("01").Select ' HARD CODED FIRST DAY
     Range("B6:F101").Select 'AREA I NEED TO COPY
    Range("B6:F101").Copy 

    wbMaster.Activate 
    Workbooks("wbMaster").ActiveSheet.Range("B65536").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues 
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 

    oWbk.Close True 'close the workbook,  saving changes
    sFil = Dir 
Loop ' End of LOOP

On Error Goto 0 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
Application.EnableEvents = True 
End Sub
```

Right now it can find the files and open them up and get to the right worksheet but when it tries to copy the data nothing is copied over.

Comment: The `(2)` part looks out of place in `.Range("B65536").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
Sheets("01").Select ' HARD CODED FIRST DAY
Range("B6:F101").Select 'AREA I NEED TO COPY
Range("B6:F101").Copy
```

Have you tried

```
oWbk.Sheets("01").Copy Before wbMaster.Sheets(1)
```

That will copy the entire sheet into your master workbook.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach but works great:

```
Sub RunCodeOnAllXLSFiles()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    c0 = "C:\Users\test\"
    c2 = Dir("C:\Users\test\*.xls")
    Do Until c2 = ""
        With Workbooks.Add(c0 & "\" & c2)
            For Each sh In .Sheets
                If Val(sh.Name) >= 1 And Val(sh.Name) <= 31 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(96, 5) = sh.Range("B6:F101").Value
                End If
            Next
            .Close False
        End With
        c2 = Dir
     Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This was provided by SNB (http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/member.php?u=61472)